# remove UITextView from SpriteKit app with animation

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit, uitextview

I have a UITextView object in my Swift/SpriteKit program but while the transition from SpriteKit scene to SpriteKit scene works well, I can't get the UITextView to animate in a similar way.

For the scene transition, I use:

```
let transition = SKTransition.flipVerticalWithDuration(1)
let newScene = GameScene(size: self.frame.size)
view?.presentScene(newScene, transition: transition)
```

And to remove the UITextView, I use

```
myUITextView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Any ideas how I can get the textView to flip on the vertical axis as well, and at the same time as the scene change?

Update:
I realised this might be too difficult to do, so I changed it to this...

```
let transition = SKTransition.revealWithDirection(.Right, duration: 1.0)
let newScene = GameScene(size: self.frame.size)
newScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
let options = UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.CalculationModeLinear
UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: options, animations: {
UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 1/2, animations: {
            self.myUITextView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(300, 0)
        })

        }, completion: {finished in
            self.myUITextView.removeFromSuperview()
    })

view?.presentScene(newScene, transition: transition)
```

The exact timing between the scene transition and the UITextView animation needs some tuning but this basically works, except for a new problem.

The new scene I'm transitioning to also has a UITextView.  This appears on top of the one I'm animating away (like pulling a card out from behind the deck).  I understand why this is happening, the presentScene function is calling the new scene, and with it, the declaration of the new UITextView. Because SpriteKit and UIKit don't work well together, this is being placed on top of the older UITextView I'm trying to remove.  Any ideas how I can achieve this animation with the old scene's UITextView being kept on top?

Update2: I've done a little experiment with the following commands:

```
let transitionOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft
var views : (frontView: UIView, backView: UIView)
views = (frontView: self.myUITextView, backView: self.UITextView)    
UIView.transitionFromView(views.frontView, toView: views.backView, duration: 1.0, options: transitionOptions, completion: nil)
```

When I did this, I expected the myUITextView to flip from the left, but to my surprise the entire SKView flipped in the way I was looking for as well.  The only problem is the toView is pointing back onto the same scene (so it flips back onto oldScene) and I want to go to newScene.  Any ideas how to point towards the new scene or open it behind the old scene?